# Close popup by Esc if there are many of them on the page

Tags: javascript, popup

I have been searching through the web, but could not find the answer to the question, which seems to have a trivial solution.

I have three popups on my page, which user can open and the functionality to open and close them looks usual:

```
const popupPicture = document.querySelector(".popup_pic");
const popupProfile = document.querySelector(".popup_profile");
const popupImage = document.querySelector(".popup_image");

function openPopup(popup) {
  popup.classList.add("popup_opened");
}

function closePopup(popup) {
  popup.classList.remove("popup_opened");
}
```

and I pass one of the popup variables to closePopup or to openPopup as a variable.
For instance

```
closePopupButton.addEventListener("click", () => closePopup(popupProfile));
closePopupImageButton.addEventListener("click", () => closePopup(popupImage));
closePopupPictureButton.addEventListener("click", () => closePopup(popupPicture));
```

The same with opening popups. I need now closing functionality by Escape button. I understand that it is easy to achieve if there is just one popup by the following code:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (evt) {
  if (evt.key === "Escape") {
    // and close popup here
  }
});
```

But there are three popups in my case and I do not know, which I should close. Of course I can do it by this ugly way:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (evt) {
  if (evt.key === "Escape") {
    closePopup(popupProfile);
    closePopup(popupImage);
    closePopup(popupPicture);
  }
});
```

And it solves my case, but I wonder if there is more elegant solution, which does not require calling two functions that should not be called.

Hopefully I stated my issue clear.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `document.getElementsByClassName()`.

This returns an `HTMLCollection` of elements that include the given class string, then you just need to iterate through it.

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/whp8xzb2/1/

The elements used in the example have multiple classes assigned to them, similar to your code. It retrieves these elements using `document.getElementsByClassName("foo")`, then it iterates through the results using a for loop:

```
for (let item of results) {
    console.log(item)
}
```